# Android Alarm with user specified alarm tone

Tags: android

what I want to do is that I have stored date and time in a database and the Id of alarm tone I want to play the specific tone on specific time and date as chosen by the user inspite of my efforts couldn't find anything like that please help..

Thanks in advance 
Aashish

Comment: paste the code in question whatever you do for this

Comment: Don't have a clue on how to do this

Comment: what clue? whatever your code for this you have written just paste(edit) in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the AlarmManager class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html